can someone add a pull request to https://github.com/iancoleman/jsbip39 so that we can generate private keys from seed phrases. sol is missing
please for the love of solana can someone add a pr to https://github.com/iancoleman/jsbip39 so that we can use that resource to generate private keys from bip39 seed phrases.  Sadly above my skill cap.
a lotta coins in the list, sol is missing and when asked why no sol, iancoleman said because nobody from SOL team has submitted a PR to add it
solana keygen source code:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/keygen/src/keygen.rs
